# Creating multiple query statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to mysql and it's entirety. I have a database which consists of three tables. I created a mysql statement which i want to query the database and pull out some information from the database. For example, the database has three tables named **airport** (which has its name and id), **planes**(which has the size of the planes) and **location**(which has the  names of the airport location) These tables also have their specific table id's. I want to create a query which is suppose get the airport location(state and city), the plane size as well the name of the airport.

so far here is my query, can someone assist me with where i am going wrong? or what direction should i take. Thanks in advance.

```
   SELECT a.plane_Size, b.STABBR,i.airport_name FROM airport i

   JOIN planes a ON i.plane_ID = a.plane_ID
   AND locations b ON b.Location_ID = i.Location_ID
   WHERE STABBR = 'WV'
   ORDER BY a.CITY;
```

Comment: airport has a plane_ID. This seems unlikely

Comment: Typically, you would have a table of airports, and a table of planes. Assuming airports don't move, and planes are intact, you wouldn't really need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am a bit new to databases, I will pay attention to relationships when designing my database. Thanks for the advice mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need join between locations and airport too:

```
SELECT a.plane_Size, b.STABBR,i.airport_name FROM airport i
JOIN planes a ON i.plane_ID = a.plane_ID
JOIN locations b ON b.Location_ID = i.Location_ID
WHERE STABBR = 'WV'
ORDER BY a.CITY;
```

Comment: @BrandonJ In which case, you may have bigger problems with your schema!

Comment: I do not understand, how would problems arise?

Comment: @BrandonJ Why would you store a plane_id in an airport table. It makes no sense.

Comment: You're right it doesn't, the airport should have a plane id. Got you.

Comment: @BrandonJ Um. No. The airport should not have a plane_id. That would imply that each airport had capacity for only one plane. In my experience, there are lots of planes at airports, but each plane is only (at most) at one airport at any given time

Comment: Oh, i see. guess it's back to the drawing board with this schema. Thanks for pointing that out.